# How does one clear the bash history?

Tags: sd-card, bash

I have been trying to free up space on my full SD card.

I've been wondering if one can clear the history in bash when one presses the up arrow. I have been unable to find a command that would enable one to do this.

Comment: As Steve explains, you are wasting your time contemplating how to throw a snowball at a line of tanks.  That cache will amount to less than 1/1000th of 1% of the space on the card.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the bash history not a cache. It is stored in the **.bash_history** file in your home directory. By default it is limited to a set number of lines (1000) and the size of the file (2000). So even if you remove it you would gain very little. You can check the size of the file by doing an `ls -lah` in your home directory. I have a custom script that stores every command I enter and in more than 16 months the file is less than 2 MBs). The pertinent settings are HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE. These are set in your .bashrc file (again located in your home directory). To find out more about HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE and the differences between them check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454837/bash-histsize-vs-histfilesize). This functionality is immensely helpful and should not be removed. I have used Linux since the mid 1990's and still use this feature daily.

If you are that constrained for disk space I would suggest that the problem lies elsewhere. To find what is utilizing the disk space you can use the **df** and **du** commands. You can learn more about these commands by typing **man du** or **man df** (tip: check out the -h option for both commands). This will load the man (manual aka help) page for the commands.